# Program won't run?

Tags: c

I am trying to make this program work, with no success. The program involves arithmetic with float types, and consists of the function temperature(), to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius. The function gets the input from a `for` loop, but when I execute it, I only get the first conversion. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

float temperature(int);

int main() {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= 300; i = i + 20)
        printf("%3d\t%6.2f\n", i, temperature(i));
    return 0;
}

float temperature(int m) {
    float low, up, step, f, t;
    float j = 5.0/9.0;
    for (f = low; f <= up; f = f + step)
       t = j * (f - 32.0);
    return t;
}
```

Comment: You doen't use `m` in `temperature`. and using uninitialized variables.

Comment: You actually did not initialized any of the variable in the function.

Comment: You also assign to `t` in every iteration of the loop inside `temperature`. The final value the function returns will be the result of the last iteration. Perhaps you should print the result *in* the loop?

Comment: You really need to just think this through. Read through your code and make sure it really makes sense. Don't just write a bunch of stuff down and wonder why it doesn't work. You've got two different loops going on, one inside and one outside the function, and you only need one. Your `temperature` function should just be returning a single temperature if you want the main loop to take care of making the table.

Comment: Thank you all guys! I'm a beginner, trying to learn C.

Comment: Your comment was helpful: Mr. Some programmer dude. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

As others said. The best way to debug the code is to analyze it. You have to understand what your code does. Plan your code. Do your best to solve the problem before asking here - that is the best way to learn.

I believe this is what you were trying to achieve:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    float fahr, celsius;

    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 20;

    fahr = lower;

    while (fahr <= upper) {
        celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0);
        printf("%3.0f\t%6.2f\n", fahr, celsius);
        fahr = fahr + step;
    }
}
```

Read carefully the code. The example above has just one function. You can easily split it into two functions by having one function responsible for temperature conversion and loop from 0 to 300 from the main loop.
If there is something that doesn't make sense - ask! That is what this forum is for.

```
#include <stdio.h>

float convert (float fahr) {

    float celsius = (5.0/9.0) * (fahr-32.0);

    return celsius;
}

int main() {

    int lower, upper, step;

    lower = 0;
    upper = 300;
    step = 20;

    float fahr = lower;

    while (fahr <= upper) {
        printf("%3.0f\t%6.2f\n", fahr, convert(fahr));
        fahr = fahr + step;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please, at minimum, use `int main()` and preferably use `int main(void)` when defining a `main()` that does not pay attention to command line arguments.  Personally, I consider it desirable to explicitly `return 0;` from `main()` — not everyone agrees.  You have `int lower, upper, step; lower = 0; upper = 300; step = 20;` — it would be much better to use: `int lower = 0; int upper = 300; int step = 20;` on separate lines. This initializes each variable as it is defined — and permits per-variable comments if they're needed.  Generally, one variable per line is good.